# Looking for a Theorem Relating Polynomial Coeffecients and Roots

Tags: polynomials

I recall seeing this theorem in a book on Euler, but I can't recall the books name nor the theorems name (if it had one). I remember reading that this theorem was originally put forth and proved by Newton then Euler created his own proof.

Here's what I recall of it:

> If $P(x)=x^n-Ax^{n-1}+Bx^{n-2}-Cx^{n-3}+ \dots \pm N$ is a polynomial who can be factored as $P(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2) \dots (x-r_n) $, then
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^n r_k = A$
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^n r_k^2 = A\sum_{k=1}^n r_k - B$

And some pattern continues, although I can only remember this much.

Comment: I think you are looking for Newton's identities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: The other identities are called "Vieta's formulas" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)